# override standard component styling

Tags: lightning, lightning-apps, css

I have a request to change the icon color of different feed items on the standard chatter feed component. Feed items that are of type question have the same color icons and field updates. A question can be easily missed if there are a lot of status updates. It looks like Salesforce has their styling for Lightning Apps on lock down, unless they are custom components.

[image]

Comment: It is actually never a good idea to do so since component class names or selectors are prone to change with updates. Therefore you are better off creating a custom component with your own styling and classes

Comment: yes, but I'd rather maintain a single css styling then create an entire custom component just to change the color of an icon :D

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately there really isn’t a clean way to do so, also, you will want to check if the dom is shadow, if it is, you wont have a choice